# How can I force my ObjectListView to refresh its column widths on new data?

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm using a ListCtrl subclass [ObjectListView](http://wiki.wxpython.org/ObjectListView), and I'm having the problem that after I set some data to the list, all columns are set to their minimum widths, and not until I resize my window do they pop into their correct widths. More specifically, one of my columns is set to resize to fill the remaining space, and it doesn't do that until I resize the window.

How do I fix this?

*(I'm using wxPython 2.9 on OSX 10.8.1 Mountain Lion)*

---

```
self.results_list = ObjectListView(self, style=wx.LC_REPORT)
self.results_list.SetColumns([
    ColumnDefn('Street name', 'left', valueGetter='streetname',
               minimumWidth=150),
    ColumnDefn('House number', 'left', valueGetter='housenumber',
               minimumWidth=100),
    ColumnDefn('Letter', 'left', valueGetter='letter',
               minimumWidth=75),
    ColumnDefn('Postal code', 'right', valueGetter='postalcode',
               minimumWidth=120),
    ColumnDefn('City', 'left', valueGetter='city', minimumWidth=100,
               isSpaceFilling=True),
])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try calling Layout on the widget's parent. Sometimes that is the sizer, the panel or the frame itself. I usually try each until I find the one that works. This has worked for me on Windows and (I think) Ubuntu.